# How to send custom header (metadata) with Python gRPC?

Tags: python, grpc

I want to know how to send custom header (or metadata) using Python gRPC. I looked into documents and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 20):

I figured out reading the code. You can send a `metadata` param to the function call, where `metadata` is a tuple of 2-tuples:

```
metadata = (('md-key', 'some value'),
            ('some-md-key', 'another value'))
response = stub.YourFunctionCall(request=request, metadata=metadata)
```

Comment: More recently this needs to be a list of 2-tuples:

metadata = [('k1', 'v1'), ('k2', 'v2')]

Comment: If you have only *one* header, like for example, `metadata = (('md-key', 'some value'))` this code will fail. You have to add them as array as follows: `metadata = [('md-key', 'some value')]`

Comment: It's not so much that the request fails but that Python won't interpret that as a 2-tuple. You can also use `metadata = (('md-key', 'some value'), )`

Answer (score 8):

Pls read the [example in github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python). 
For example:

```py
        response, call = stub.SayHello.with_call(
            helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'),
            metadata=(
                ('initial-metadata-1', 'The value should be str'),
                ('binary-metadata-bin',
                 b'With -bin surffix, the value can be bytes'),
                ('accesstoken', 'gRPC Python is great'),
            ))
```

Or if you want to define a interceptor

```py
        metadata = []
        if client_call_details.metadata is not None:
            metadata = list(client_call_details.metadata)
        metadata.append((
            header,
            value,
        ))
        client_call_details = _ClientCallDetails(
            client_call_details.method, client_call_details.timeout, metadata,
            client_call_details.credentials)
```

Something important is that the metadata's key can not has upper case character (It has troubled me for a long time).

Comment: Direct link to the example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/metadata/metadata_client.py

Comment: Metadata keys must be lowercase chars.  That's just horrible and frustrating.  `ValueError: metadata was invalid`

Answer (score 1):

If you metadata has one key/value you can only use list(eg: [(key, value)]) ,If you metadata has Mult k/v you should use list(eg: [(key1, value1), (key2,value2)]) or tuple(eg: ((key1, value1), (key2,value2))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: please consider editing your answer to include proper formatting, and to add references and/or links to supporting materials.