# Python gRPC client request only with bearer token

Tags: python, client, grpc, bearer-token

I followed the instructions of generating a Python gPRC client from [here](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python/#client) but struggle to provide a token to the request

**Insecure Channel does not work**

```
auth_creds = grpc.access_token_call_credentials(TOKEN)
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:10000', auth_creds)

>> TypeError: 'CallCredentials' object is not iterable
```

**Secure Channel does not work either**

```
auth_creds = grpc.access_token_call_credentials(TOKEN)
channel = grpc.secure_channel('localhost:10000', auth_creds)

>> TypeError: Argument 'channel_credentials' has incorrect type (expected grpc._cython.cygrpc.ChannelCredentials, got grpc._cython.cygrpc.MetadataPluginCallCredentials)
```

According to [python gRPC documentation](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#authentication-authorization-objects)

> A CallCredentials has to be used with secure Channel, otherwise the metadata will not be transmitted to the server.

However, how do I create a secure channel, since methods which create these ChannelCredentials correspond to ssl or similar, no?

In addition to that, it seems to be possible to simply parse the tuple `{'Authorization':'Bearer <TOKEN>'}` as meta data like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071567/how-to-send-custom-header-metadata-with-python-grpc). However, I noticed - as in the comment raised - upper case characters are not allowed.

**with_call Method with credentials does not also not work**

```
auth_creds = grpc.access_token_call_credentials(TOKEN)
channel = grpc.secure_channel('localhost:10000', auth_creds)
stub = foo_bar_pb2_grpc.ServiceStub(channel)
response = stub.Get.with_call(message_pb2.Message(), credentials=auth_creds)

>> TypeError: Argument 'channel_credentials' has incorrect type (expected grpc._cython.cygrpc.ChannelCredentials, got grpc._cython.cygrpc.MetadataPluginCallCredentials)
```

**with_call Method with metadata does not also not work**

```
metadata = 'Authorization', 'Bearer <TOKEN>'
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:10000')
stub = foo_bar_pb2_grpc.ServiceStub(channel)
response = stub.Get.with_call(message_pb2.Message(), metadata=metadata))

>> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Summarized: How do I authenticate my client with an access token?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue trying to send a custom header in a secure channel.

In my case, the problem came from using:

```
metadata = (('my-header-key', 'my-header-value'))
```

Instead of:

```
metadata = [('my-header-key', 'my-header-value')]
```

My code:

```
credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
with grpc.secure_channel("<HOST>:<PORT>", credentials) as channel:
    rpc_service = my_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(channel)
    request = my_pb2.MyData(my_data='data')
    metadata = [('my-header-key', 'my-header-value')]
    response = rpc_service.MyMethod(request=request, metadata=metadata)
```

Comment: The code snippet was helpful, but your problem was mis-diagnosed. You can use a tuple for metadata (not a list), but a 1-element tuple must have a trailing `,`, e.g., `metadata = (('my-header-key', 'my-header-value'),)`. Otherwise, the parentheses are parsed as simply a grouping operation, not a tuple creation.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the same [docstring](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.CallCredentials):

> A CallCredentials may be composed with ChannelCredentials to always
>   assert identity for every call over that Channel.

and a `ChannelCredentials` object is what your type error from `grpc.secure_channel` was screaming for.
To do that composition, you need to encrypt the channel with SSL/TLS.
Here is a client example with a token:

```py
with open("server.crt", 'rb') as fd:
    root_c = fd.read()
scc = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=root_c)

tok = grpc.access_token_call_credentials("super-secret-token")
ccc = grpc.composite_channel_credentials(scc, tok)

with grpc.secure_channel("localhost:8080", ccc) as channel:
    #... create stub and do the call
    pass
```

For some more complete examples with SSL checkout this https://github.com/joekottke/python-grpc-ssl or this https://www.sandtable.com/using-ssl-with-grpc-in-python/. The [official doc](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) might also be helpful to look at.

A token is something you don't want anyone to sniff and I guess that's why you are required to use it in a `secure_channel` by the gRPC library.